# Uniform Cost Search Implementation

Tags: java, search

I am trying to implement the Uniform Cost Search after watching the "Intro to AI" course in Udacity. However, my algorithm is not getting the correct path. Have been trying the whole day before posting here. I have added a map to help to visualize the scene. The algorithm should find the shortest weighted path from Arad to Bucharest[image: Romania Map]

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

//diff between uniform cost search and dijkstra algo is that UCS has a goal

public class UniformCostSearchAlgo{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //initialize the graph base on the Romania map
        Node n1 = new Node("Arad");
        Node n2 = new Node("Zerind");
        Node n3 = new Node("Oradea");
        Node n4 = new Node("Sibiu");
        Node n5 = new Node("Fagaras");
        Node n6 = new Node("Rimnicu Vilcea");
        Node n7 = new Node("Pitesti");
        Node n8 = new Node("Timisoara");
        Node n9 = new Node("Lugoj");
        Node n10 = new Node("Mehadia");
        Node n11 = new Node("Drobeta");
        Node n12 = new Node("Craiova");
        Node n13 = new Node("Bucharest");
        Node n14 = new Node("Giurgiu");

        //initialize the edges
        n1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n2,75),
            new Edge(n4,140),
            new Edge(n8,118)
        };

        n2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n1,75),
            new Edge(n3,71)
        };

        n3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n2,71),
            new Edge(n4,151)
        };

        n4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n1,140),
            new Edge(n5,99),
            new Edge(n3,151),
            new Edge(n6,80),
        };

        n5.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n4,99),
            new Edge(n13,211)
        };

        n6.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n4,80),
            new Edge(n7,97),
            new Edge(n12,146)
        };

        n7.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n6,97),
            new Edge(n13,101),
            new Edge(n12,138)
        };

        n8.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n1,118),
            new Edge(n9,111)
        };

        n9.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n8,111),
            new Edge(n10,70)
        };

        n10.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n9,70),
            new Edge(n11,75)
        };

        n11.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n10,75),
            new Edge(n12,120)
        };

        n12.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n11,120),
            new Edge(n6,146),
            new Edge(n7,138)
        };

        n13.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n7,101),
            new Edge(n14,90),
            new Edge(n5,211)
        };

        n14.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n13,90)
        };

        UniformCostSearch(n1,n13);

        List<Node> path = printPath(n13);

        System.out.println("Path: " + path);

    }

    public static void UniformCostSearch(Node source, Node goal){

        source.pathCost = 0;
        PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(20, 
            new Comparator<Node>(){

                //override compare method
                public int compare(Node i, Node j){
                    if(i.pathCost > j.pathCost){
                        return 1;
                    }

                    else if (i.pathCost < j.pathCost){
                        return -1;
                    }

                    else{
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }

        );

        queue.add(source);
        Set<Node> explored = new HashSet<Node>();
        boolean found = false;

        //while frontier is not empty
        do{

            Node current = queue.poll();
            explored.add(current);


            if(current.value.equals(goal.value)){
                found = true;


            }




            for(Edge e: current.adjacencies){
                Node child = e.target;
                double cost = e.cost;
                child.pathCost = current.pathCost + cost;



                if(!explored.contains(child) && !queue.contains(child)){

                    child.parent = current;
                    queue.add(child);

                    System.out.println(child);
                    System.out.println(queue);
                    System.out.println();

                }


                else if((queue.contains(child))&&(child.pathCost>current.pathCost)){

                    child.parent=current;
                    current = child;

                }


            }
        }while(!queue.isEmpty());

    }

    public static List<Node> printPath(Node target){
        List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
        for(Node node = target; node!=null; node = node.parent){
            path.add(node);
        }

        Collections.reverse(path);

        return path;

    }

}

class Node{

    public final String value;
    public double pathCost;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public Node parent;

    public Node(String val){

        value = val;

    }

    public String toString(){
        return value;
    }

}

class Edge{
    public final double cost;
    public final Node target;

    public Edge(Node targetNode, double costVal){
        cost = costVal;
        target = targetNode;

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: @Dom, I have added a map to explain a bit more. I am trying to find the shortest path from Arad to Bucharest. The path should be [Arad, Sibiu, Rimnicu Vilcea, Pitesti, Bucharest]. But I am getting [Arad, Sibiu, Fagaras, Bucharest]

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I manage to figure out! Apparently, I added a 2-way edges instead of just 1-way edges. Instead of having Edge e1 going from Node A to Node B and Edge e2 going from Node B to Node A, I remove e2, such that it becomes a single directed graph. Thus, the algorithm works!

Comment: But the graph in the example is not directed and the algorithm should work on undirected graphs.  Also there might be a problem with the queue.  The `java.util.PriorityQueue` is not really laid out for decreasing keyes like the ones you get in the shorttest path algorithms.  You can get that effect by removing a node and adding it back again, but this has not the same complexity as intended.  `PriorityQueue` is meant for the case where the keyes(/priorities) do not change once an object has been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your algorith is the part when you find a new shorter path to a node that is already in the queue.  You should not set `current` outside the call to `poll` as this breaks the algorithms scheme.  Instead you should decrease the key/priority/current-shortest-path-cost of the node.

I've updated your code to do this.  It provides the expected result.  But like I said in a comment, when it comes to asymptotic complexity this is not the most efficient solution.  The best option is to find or write a `PriorityQueue` that supports dynamically keys efficiently.

But here is the updated code:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

//diff between uniform cost search and dijkstra algo is that UCS has a goal

public class UniformCostSearchAlgo{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //initialize the graph base on the Romania map
        Node n1 = new Node("Arad");
        Node n2 = new Node("Zerind");
        Node n3 = new Node("Oradea");
        Node n4 = new Node("Sibiu");
        Node n5 = new Node("Fagaras");
        Node n6 = new Node("Rimnicu Vilcea");
        Node n7 = new Node("Pitesti");
        Node n8 = new Node("Timisoara");
        Node n9 = new Node("Lugoj");
        Node n10 = new Node("Mehadia");
        Node n11 = new Node("Drobeta");
        Node n12 = new Node("Craiova");
        Node n13 = new Node("Bucharest");
        Node n14 = new Node("Giurgiu");

        //initialize the edges
        n1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n2,75),
            new Edge(n4,140),
            new Edge(n8,118)
        };

        n2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n1,75),
            new Edge(n3,71)
        };

        n3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n2,71),
            new Edge(n4,151)
        };

        n4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n1,140),
            new Edge(n5,99),
            new Edge(n3,151),
            new Edge(n6,80),
        };

        n5.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n4,99),
            new Edge(n13,211)
        };

        n6.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n4,80),
            new Edge(n7,97),
            new Edge(n12,146)
        };

        n7.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n6,97),
            new Edge(n13,101),
            new Edge(n12,138)
        };

        n8.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n1,118),
            new Edge(n9,111)
        };

        n9.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n8,111),
            new Edge(n10,70)
        };

        n10.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n9,70),
            new Edge(n11,75)
        };

        n11.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n10,75),
            new Edge(n12,120)
        };

        n12.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n11,120),
            new Edge(n6,146),
            new Edge(n7,138)
        };

        n13.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n7,101),
            new Edge(n14,90),
            new Edge(n5,211)
        };

        n14.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
            new Edge(n13,90)
        };

        UniformCostSearch(n1,n13);

        List<Node> path = printPath(n13);

        System.out.println("Path: " + path);

    }

    public static void UniformCostSearch(Node source, Node goal){

        source.pathCost = 0;
        PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(20, 
            new Comparator<Node>(){

                //override compare method
                public int compare(Node i, Node j){
                    if(i.pathCost > j.pathCost){
                        return 1;
                    }

                    else if (i.pathCost < j.pathCost){
                        return -1;
                    }

                    else{
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }

        );

        queue.add(source);
        Set<Node> explored = new HashSet<Node>();
        boolean found = false;

        //while frontier is not empty
        do{

            Node current = queue.poll();
            explored.add(current);


            if(current.value.equals(goal.value)){
                found = true;


            }




            for(Edge e: current.adjacencies){
                Node child = e.target;
                double cost = e.cost;
                child.pathCost = current.pathCost + cost;



                if(!explored.contains(child) && !queue.contains(child)){

                    child.parent = current;
                    queue.add(child);

                    System.out.println(child);
                    System.out.println(queue);
                    System.out.println();

                }
                else if((queue.contains(child))&&(child.pathCost>current.pathCost)){
                    child.parent=current;

                    // the next two calls decrease the key of the node in the queue
                    queue.remove(child);
                    queue.add(child);
                }


            }
        }while(!queue.isEmpty());

    }

    public static List<Node> printPath(Node target){
        List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
        for(Node node = target; node!=null; node = node.parent){
            path.add(node);
        }

        Collections.reverse(path);

        return path;

    }

}

class Node{

    public final String value;
    public double pathCost;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public Node parent;

    public Node(String val){

        value = val;

    }

    public String toString(){
        return value;
    }

}

class Edge{
    public final double cost;
    public final Node target;

    public Edge(Node targetNode, double costVal){
        cost = costVal;
        target = targetNode;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Viktor. Now, if I changed the distance from Fagaras to Buscharest to a value which is a lot lower(example just 1) which will make it a shorter path, the algorithm will now not return this new shorter path. Instead it still maintains [Arad, Sibiu, Rimnicu Vilcea, Pitesti, Bucharest]  when it should now be [Arad, Sibiu, Fagaras, Bucharest]. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ray.R.Chua Can you check that you have correctly set the edge length and recompiled?  For me the updated algorithm shows the expected result.  See the run on ideone: http://ideone.com/KCqfXM

Answer (score 0):

This is solved problem of Uniform Cost Search with added path, what is wrong in your algorithm.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;

public class UniformCostSearchAlgo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Node n1 = new Node("Arad");
Node n2 = new Node("Zerind");
Node n3 = new Node("Oradea");
Node n4 = new Node("Sibiu");
Node n5 = new Node("Fagaras");
Node n6 = new Node("Rimnicu Vilcea");
Node n7 = new Node("Pitesti");
Node n8 = new Node("Timisoara");
Node n9 = new Node("Lugoj");
Node n10 = new Node("Mehadia");
Node n11 = new Node("Drobeta");
Node n12 = new Node("Craiova");
Node n13 = new Node("Bucharest");
Node n14 = new Node("Giurgiu");

// initialize the edges
n1.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n2, 75), new Edge(n4, 140),
        new Edge(n8, 118) };

n2.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n1, 75), new Edge(n3, 71) };

n3.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n2, 71), new Edge(n4, 151) };

n4.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n1, 140), new Edge(n5, 99),
        new Edge(n3, 151), new Edge(n6, 80), };

n5.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n4, 99), new Edge(n13, 211) };

n6.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n4, 80), new Edge(n7, 97),
        new Edge(n12, 146) };

n7.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n6, 97), new Edge(n13, 101),
        new Edge(n12, 138) };

n8.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n1, 118), new Edge(n9, 111) };

n9.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n8, 111), new Edge(n10, 70) };

n10.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n9, 70), new Edge(n11, 75) };

n11.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n10, 75), new Edge(n12, 120) };

n12.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n11, 120), new Edge(n6, 146),
        new Edge(n7, 138) };

n13.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n7, 101), new Edge(n14, 90),
        new Edge(n5, 211) };

n14.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(n13, 90) };

UniformCostSearch(n1, n13);

List<Node> path = printPath(n13);

System.out.println("Path: " + path);

}

public static void UniformCostSearch(Node source, Node goal) {

List<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>();
source.pathCost = 0;
PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(20,
        new Comparator<Node>() {

            // override compare method
            public int compare(Node i, Node j) {
                if ((i.pathCost > j.pathCost)) {
                    return 1;
                }

                else if (i.pathCost < j.pathCost) {
                    return -1;
                }

                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

);

queue.add(source);
Set<Node> explored = new HashSet<Node>();
List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();

// while frontier is not empty
do {

    path.clear();
    Node current = queue.poll();
    explored.add(current);
    for (Node node = current; node != null; node = node.parent) {
        path.add(node);
    }
    if (current.value.equals(goal.value)) {
        goal.parent = current.parent;
        goal.pathCost = current.pathCost;
        break;

    }

    for (Edge e : current.adjacencies) {
        Node child = e.target;
        double cost = e.cost;
        if ((queue.contains(child) || explored.contains(child))
                && !path.contains(child)) {
            Node n = new Node(child);
            list.add(n);
            list.get(list.size() - 1).pathCost = current.pathCost
                    + cost;
            list.get(list.size() - 1).parent = current;
            queue.add(list.get(list.size() - 1));

            System.out.println(list.get(list.size() - 1));
            System.out.println(queue);
        } else if (!path.contains(child)) {
            child.pathCost = current.pathCost + cost;
            child.parent = current;
            queue.add(child);

            System.out.println(child);
            System.out.println(queue);
        }

    }
} while (!queue.isEmpty());

}

public static List<Node> printPath(Node target) {
List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
for (Node node = target; node != null; node = node.parent) {
    path.add(node);
}

Collections.reverse(path);

return path;

}
}
class Node {
public final String value;
public double pathCost;
public Edge[] adjacencies;
public Node parent;

public Node(String val) {

value = val;

}

public Node(Node node) {
int i = 0;
adjacencies = new Edge[node.adjacencies.length];
value = node.value;
pathCost = node.pathCost;
for (Edge e : node.adjacencies) {
    adjacencies[i++] = e;
}
parent = node.parent;
}

public String toString() {
return value + pathCost + "   ";
}

}
class Edge {
public final double cost;
public final Node target;

public Edge(Node targetNode, double costVal) {
cost = costVal;
target = targetNode;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of code

```
else if((queue.contains(child))&&(child.pathCost>current.pathCost)){

                            child.parent=current;
                            current = child;

                    }
```

to

```
 else if((queue.contains(child))&&(child.pathCost>current.pathCost+cost)){

                            child.parent=current;
                            child.pathCost = current.pathCost+cost;
                            queue.remove(child);
                            queue.add(child);


                    }
```