# Java Uniform Cost Search

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

I'm new to Java. Just learning.
I've taken up an AI class so it requires me to do the following search algorithm.
***UCS - uniform Cost Search Algorithm in Java***
here is the sample [input file](https://omega.uta.edu/~gopikrishnav/classes/2017/fall/ai1/assmts/assmt1_files/input1.txt).
check this image > [map route for UCS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxlHw.jpg)
Implement a search algorithm that can find a route between any two cities. Your program will be called find_route, and will take exactly three commandline arguments, as follows:

```
find_route input_filename origin_city destination_city

An example command line is:
    ***find_route input1.txt Munich Berlin***

**Examples:**
1. route: Bremen to Dortmund, 234  
2.find_route input1.txt London Frankfurt
Should have the following output:
**distance: infinity**
*route: none*
```

I'm working upon parsing the input and I'm stuck as to where I go next?
Also, I am using an arraylist to store data, but facing problem with the iterator to display those elements. Should I be using some different data structure? Please help!

**EDIT: or maybe try the post below and make it dynamic to accept file and connections? :D**
[This POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635394/uniform-cost-search-implementation)

main test.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Reading File");
        ArrayList<GraphNode> graphList = new ArrayList<GraphNode>();

        java.util.Iterator<GraphNode> itr=graphList.iterator();  

        File file = new File("C://Users/liquidf4ntasy/workspace/test/src/com/jbt/input_file1.txt"); 
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file); 

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] fields = line.split(" ");

                graphList.add(new GraphNode(String.valueOf(fields[0]),
                                            String.valueOf(fields[1]),
                                            Integer.parseInt(fields[2])   )    );
                System.out.println("Contents added: "  + fields[0] + " " + fields[1] + " " + fields[2]);

            }
            scanner.close(); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Reached End of Line"); 
    }

        // still inside void main!
        System.out.println("outside!");
        //traverse elements of ArrayList object  
      //    GraphNode gl=(GraphNode)itr.next();
    //      System.out.println(gl.start+" "+gl.end+" "+gl.cost);  


    }

}
```

GraphNode.java

```
class GraphNode {
String start;
String end;
int cost;

public GraphNode(String start, String end, int cost) {                
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.cost = cost;
}

public String getStart() {
        return start;
}

public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
}

public String getEnd() {
        return end;
}

public void setEnd(String end) {
        this.end = end;
}

public int getCost() {
        return cost;
}

public void setCost(int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}
```

}